# Create an order of a given product and current user in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have scaffolded a database for products and there are users which are supposed to create orders by pressing a button next to the product. I don't quite understand what is going on but I get an error message when as a user I try to order a product. Also this product should be displayed on a view of the user where all orders can be seen. I also do not understand how to set this up.

```html
undefined method `orders' for nil:NilClass
```

My orders_controller:

```html
 def create
  if @current_user.orders.create(params[:order])
      order[product_id] = params[:order][product_id]
    else 
    end
 end
```

My users controller:

```html
  def order
    @order = Order.new
  end
```

And where the button is supposed to create a product:

```html
><%= button_to 'Order', {:controller => "orders", :action => "create"}, :product_id => product.id, :user_id=> session[:user_id] %>
```

Comment: Are you using Devise for authentication ?

Comment: How to solve this depends on what you goal is. If users must sign up before adding any items to their cart you should check before the action and redirect to the sign in. With devise you would do this by calling `before_action :authenticate_user!`. If not then you need to create a "guest user" account that is finalized when the user checks out.

Comment: Yes, I use Devise.
Users need to be signed up, correct. I am not sure where to but that before_action though.

Comment: @CherianGrundmann in that case use `current_user` instead of `@current_user` :)

Comment: `before_action :authenticate_user!` goes in the body of the controller class.

Comment: Ok, thank you. However the authenticate feature was something I wanted add later. I am using current_user now and I get this error. I am sure I am using the wrong code here... undefined local variable or method `order' for #<OrdersController:0x007fbcd458a550> Did you mean? order_url Extracted source (around line #13): ... order[product_id] = params[:order][product_id] ....  <=Thats what I have in my if condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using devise to manage your `User` then the current user is accessible by a method `current_user`.   The instance variable `@current_user` contains nothing (nil).   Note that instance variables you assign in one cycle are not availabel the next time a form is submitted or a link is followed.

Answer (score 1):

If your application requires an order to be linked to a user you should bail early and require authentication. With Devise you would use:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # ...
end
```

This redirects the user to the sign in page if they are not signed in.

Comment: You are adding unnecessary information and just repeating what other users have answered already.

Comment: None of the other answers mention using `authenticate_user!` to solve the actual root of the problem @Cyzanfar

Comment: That isn't the root of the problem. The user did not mention anything about sessions.

Comment: "Yes, I use Devise. Users need to be signed up, correct. I am not sure where to but that before_action though." @Cyzanfar - stop trolling. I have removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Devise Ruby gem for authentication then you should remove the `@` from `@current_user` as Devise provides a helper method for accessing the current user signed in. Just call `current_user.orders`. 
`@current_user` is `nil` since you are not assigning it anywhere in the create method.

Check it out here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

Comment: You should read the question asked first before commenting. This solves the problem since `@current_user` is never assigned anywhere so will always return nil

Comment: The OP has not stated anywhere that they are using devise so there might not even be a current_user method. If current_user returns nil this still gives a nil error.

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. Spin up a rails app and test it.

Comment: Nope, it works. `current_user.orders` doesn't return `undefined method orders for nil:NilClass` anymore. Instead it return an ActiveRecord association object. Remove your unnecessary down vote.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails authentication gem **Devise** then you will have a helper method **current_user** instead **@current_user** variable. So, you code should be like below,

```
def create
  if current_user.orders.create(params[:order])
    # Your code should go here
  end
end
```